# php string backslash followed by digit

Tags: php

I have a variable that is set by a file path. The path is dynamically set based on date as such

```
  $str = "IMAGES\2016\08\01\NM.jpg"
```

notice the backslashes followed by digits. This is set by the server and I cannot alter it before it reaches my php file, however it seems to be causing those characters to encode, thus making my script break.

I've tried to use str_replace to change the backslashes to forward slashes but according to my understanding of [the php manual on blackslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), it is being encoded before the function has a chance to run.

**My question is this:**

Is there a way to change how php is reading that string? or is there a way I can alter it so that it becomes usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash within the string `$str` is escaping the character immediately following it, you can prevent this behaviour by using single quotes, or; you can escape the backslash (wait for it...) by using a backslash.

```
echo $str = "IMAGES\2016\08\01\NM.jpg";
```

Result: `IMAGES?68\NM.jpg`

```
echo $str = "IMAGES\\2016\\08\\01\\NM.jpg";
```

Result: `IMAGES\2016\08\01\NM.jpg`

Aside: You could use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace each single backslash with two backslashes.

Comment: Thanks William,  my main problem was by using double quotes the digits following the backslashes were encoding in some weird way, and I had no way of escaping it prior to the variable being set because it is being fetched from a DB.. i swear i tried single quotes before I posted my question, but for some reason didn't work till I went back and tried it later on :)  chock it up to a case of the Wednesdays?

Comment: We've all been there staring at something that seems obvious but takes forever to click. More caffeine for you! ...or less.